# Can I force an expression to be treated as a constant by numba?

Tags: python, numba

Given some global non-mutated object of some type not known to numba:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
a = SimpleNamespace(b=2)
```

I'd like to be able to reference a member of this object as a compile-time constant within a jitted function, something like this:

```
@numba.njit
def foo():
    # return a.b   # fails, because numba tries to evaluate at runtime
    return numba.mark_this_as_constant(a.b)
```

Does `mark_this_as_constant` exist in numba under a different name already? Is it possible to write this myself, perhaps with a custom type?

I can get what I want today with:

```py
def foo(a_b=a.b):
   @numba.njit
   def foo():
       return a_b
   return foo
foo = foo()
```

but this is pretty gross, and requires me to list every closure at the top, rather than at the point of use.

Comment: Filed a feature request [upstream here](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5339)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this?

```
a = SimpleNamespace(b=2)
a_b = a.b

@numba.njit
def foo():
    return a_b
```